# How can I debug typescript depending on where I set a breakpoint in a yarn workspace?

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have the following launch.json file since I am using ts-node:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "ts-node/register"],
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/packages/first/src/index.ts"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently it is set to debug the index.ts inside the `first` project but what if I want to debug the `second` project assuming there is one with the same structure? I tried specifying a glob pattern like `"${workspaceFolder}/packages/**/src/index.ts"` but that did not seem to work, is there a way to achieve this without having to change the folder path everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to debug multiple programs, so you should add multiple configurations. Nothing stops you from adding multiple configs in the `launch.json`, and naming them for each project. This let you select from VSCode which program you want to launch and debug easily.

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program: First",
      "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "ts-node/register"],
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/packages/first/src/index.ts"]
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program: Second",
      "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "ts-node/register"],
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/packages/second/src/index.ts"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you! I never used a debugger before but now it makes sense to me why  there's a dropdown for tasks

Comment: however, it still seems broken when you are debugging one project in a multi workspace repo and it includes/uses source from another (library) project in the same repo...after spending 2 days, I cannot find any way to have vscode set a bound breakpoint on the library (!) code...

Comment: You can use `preLaunchTask` and specify a task in vscode. E.g., You could create a task called 'Build Code' and it would build all your code first, then launch. A second option is to point your launch to a package.json script that would first build and then launch. The good thing about a task is you can invoke it once and have it running in the background (`watch` mode), for example, it could do an incremental build on every file save.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

on `{monorepo-root-dir}/.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug app",
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": ["app:dev"]
    },
  ]
}
```

on `{monorepo-root-dir}/package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "poc-yarn2-typescript",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.2.3",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "app",
    "modules/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "app:dev": "yarn workspace @scope/app run dev"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.8.2"
  }
}
```

and finally on your `{monorepo-root-dir}/app/package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "@scope/app",
  "description": "description",
  "authors": "author",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "private": true,
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.2.3",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/main.js",
    "dev": "ts-node src/main.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@scope/lib-one": "workspace:^"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

my monorepo directory structure layout looks like this:

[image]

The full source code is here

https://github.com/alansferreira/template-yarnpkg-typescript